# Magento: sort products by attribute position

Tags: magento, attributes, position, product

In my site i have setted a filter for ordering my products by attribute, but the order is alphabetical and i would like the order is by position attribute setted in backend.

example attribute color:

Valuename | Position

green | 1

blue | 2

red | 3

The actual result in frontend is product blue then green then red, i would like the result is green then blue then red

what classes i can modify for resolving this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not cross-post on different Stack Exchange sites. And if you do, at least have the decency to not copy the 0 votes thing on the question at magento.SE

Comment: sorry I did not know they were two connected sites

Answer (score 4):

I am thinking that you create the custom option for a product and then set the short_order of the value. If this is right then use this code.

Go to the App/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option.php

There is a function getProductOptionCollection Line no:- 373 . just comment out the code of ->setOrder('title', 'asc'); and add the " ; " just after the ->setOrder('sort_order', 'asc')

```
public function getProductOptionCollection(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
{
    $collection = $this->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $product->getId())
        ->addTitleToResult($product->getStoreId())
        ->addPriceToResult($product->getStoreId())
        ->setOrder('sort_order', 'asc');
        //->setOrder('title', 'asc');

    if ($this->getAddRequiredFilter()) {
        $collection->addRequiredFilter($this->getAddRequiredFilterValue());
    }

    $collection->addValuesToResult($product->getStoreId());
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: sorry but your solution not work. the sort remaining by alphabetical attribute

Comment: can you add the screen shot of the front end .that will be much better for me.Thanks

Comment: sorry, it is currently difficult.

Comment: do you have any link so that i can check the product view page.

Comment: for example in frontend in category "TEXT" i have four product: "PRODUCT A" with attribute color green; "PRODUCT B" with attribute color red; "PRODUCT C" with attribute color grenn; "PRODUCT D" with attribute color blue......... the actual order display (when the sort filter is setted on COLOR) is  D,A,C,B but i would like A,C,D,B

Comment: i don't have a link because is actual in local computer

Comment: Yes i checked in magento core files. For this we have to do the lots of custom code. i am trying that..

Comment: i tried a lot but it is not supported in default magento. it may be possible if we make a new module for this and overwrite the catalog/product/toolbar model.

Comment: thanks for your time. there is a function that deals establish the order to be able to modify?